# Test Angular scope variables inside ajax request with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I would like to know how to test some Angular scope variables at my controller that was created inside an ajax request.

What I mean is... This is my controller:

```
app.controller('NewQuestionCtrl', function ($scope, Question) {
   loadJsonAndSetScopeVariables($scope, Question);
});

function loadJsonAndSetScopeVariables(scope, Question) {
  Question.loadJson().then(function(success) {
  var result = success.data.variables;

  scope.levels = result.levels;
  scope.tags = result.tags;
  scope.difficulties = result.difficulties;
  scope.questionTypes = result.questionTypes;
  scope.areas = result.areas;

},function(data){

 });
}
```

One of the prerequisites is not to use mock.
At my test I was able to inject my Question service:

```
describe('Controller: NewQuestionCtrl', function () {

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('testmeApp'));

var NewQuestionCtrl, scope, QuestionService;

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, Question) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  QuestionService = Question;
  NewQuestionCtrl = $controller('NewQuestionCtrl', {
  $scope: scope
 });
}));

it('should attach a list of areas to the scope', function (done) {
  expect(scope.areas).toBeDefined();
  done();
});
```

Please, someone could help me?

Answer (score 1):

Create a mock for Question and use that. There are several ways to do this. This is just one of them.

You could alternatively inject a real instance of Question and spy on that instead, but a mock is preferred to isolate these unit tests from the Question unit tests.

```
var questionDeferred, myController, scope;
var mockQuestion = {
  loadJson: angular.noop
};

beforeEach(inject(function($q, $rootScope, $controller) {
  questionDeferred = $q.defer();
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  spyOn(mockQuestion, 'loadJson').and.returnValue(questionDeferred);

  // Because your function is run straight away, you'll need to create
  // your controller in this way in order to spy on Question.loadJson()
  myController = $controller('NewQuestionCtrl', {
    $scope: scope,
    Question: mockQuestion
  });
}));

it('should attach a list of areas to the scope', function (done) {
  questionDeferred.resolve({/*some data*/});
  scope.$digest();

  expect(scope.areas).toBeDefined();
  done();
});
```

Comment: Hi @HankScorpio, thanks for your help, I really appreciate, but I forgot to say one of the prerequisites is not to use mock. I edit my question putting all my test code.

Comment: Then you're writing an integration test, not a unit test. That's fine, if that's your intent. Look at the it() block in the code i wrote.
Note that i've added two things to your code. You need them both. questionDeferred.resolve(); and scope.$digest();
Are you doing something like that somewhere?

Comment: I tried but I'm very newer with jasmine + angular tests. What I could see is that I need to create the request response with questionDeferred.resolve, this is what I want to avoid and didn't figure out how to do this even with your clues =/

Comment: In another words, is it possible to what is done here http://jasonmore.net/unit-testing-http-service-angular-js/ without mock?

Comment: No, you've got to provide a promise for your code to handle.